# empty Object when accessing it from inside of socket.on() inside of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am developing a multiplayer game in a web browser and I use react and socket.io.
In the code below, I have a react component which handles and displays the player list and their score.

- When the player entered the right answer, a socket event is emmited at server side and is caught by socket.on("rightAnswer",...)
- Every seconds, a socket event is emmited at server side and is caught by socket.on("updateScore",...). In the callback function, I try to access the scoreList object (which is a prop of my react component and it is a useState() in a parent component). Then, I have a variable temp which is the incremented score for 1 player and finally, I update my scoreList

isWinnerList should look like:
{player1: False,
player2: False,
...
}
and scoreList is similar but instead of boolean, it stores integers.

What I don't understand is my objects isWinnerList and scoreList look empty when I do a console.log and my scores are not updated.

Do I miss something with the scope ? I would expect my props and States to be available anywhere inside my react component.

Thanks in advance for your answers

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { SocketContext } from '../../context/socket';
import PlayerBoard from './PlayerBoard/PlayerBoard';

import './Scoreboard.css';

const Scoreboard = ({users, scoreList, setScoreList}) => {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  const [isWinnerList, setIsWinnerList] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('rightAnswer', ({ user }) => {
      console.log(isWinnerList);
      console.log(isWinnerList[user]);

      let temp = {};
      temp[user] = true;
      setIsWinnerList(isWinnerList => ({...isWinnerList,...temp}));
    });
    
    socket.on('updateScore', ({users}) => {
      console.log(scoreList);//this displays an empty Object
      console.log(isWinnerList);//this displays an empty Object
      for(const user of users){
        let temp = {};
        if(isWinnerList[user.name] === false){
          console.log("updating score");
          temp[user.name] = scoreList[user.name] + 3;
          setScoreList(scoreList => ({...scoreList,...temp}));
        } else {
          // console.log("user " + user.name + " has won");
        }
      }
    });
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      let temp = {};
      if(!(users[i].name in isWinnerList)){
        // console.log("adding " + users[i].name);
        temp[users[i].name] = false;
        setIsWinnerList( isWinnerList => ({...isWinnerList, ...temp}));
      }
    }
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <div className='outerScoreboard'>
      {users
        ? (
          <div className='innerScoreboard'>
            {users.map(({ name }) => (
              <div key={name} className='scoreboardItem'>
                <PlayerBoard name={name} isWinner={isWinnerList[name]} score={scoreList[name]} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )
        : <div> no users </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
};
export default Scoreboard;
```

after Alexander's answer, it tried this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('rightAnswer', ({ user }) => {
      console.log(isWinnerList);
      console.log(user);
      console.log(isWinnerList[user]);

      let temp = {};
      temp[user] = true;
      setIsWinnerList(isWinnerList => ({ ...isWinnerList, ...temp }));
    });
  }, [socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // socket.on('updateScore', test);
    console.log("useEffect executed");

    socket.on('updateScore', ({ users }) => {
      console.log(scoreList);
      console.log(isWinnerList);

      for (const user of users) {
        let temp = {};
        if (isWinnerList[user.name] === false) {
          console.log("updating score");
          temp[user.name] = scoreList[user.name] + 3;
          setScoreList(scoreList => ({ ...scoreList, ...temp }));
        } else {
          // console.log("user " + user.name + " has won");
        }
      }
    });
  }, [isWinnerList]);
```

but code inside of socket.on('updateScore',...) is executed twice now. (while the console.log("useEffect executed") is executed only once. How ? )

Terminal also gives me warning and tell me to add scoreList, setScoreList and socket to the dependency list. I would expect an infinite loop there. When I run the code with the full dependency list, socket.on("updateScore",...) is each time executed more times. Resulting in a "quasi" infinite loop

Comment: This is called "stale closure", for changes to be picked up, you would need to add the state variables such as `isWinnerList` to be part of the dependency list. Can move the `updateScore` portion to a new hook that has `isWinnerList` as a dependency. Will definitely want to have it return a function where you delete/off the socket listener to ensure it gets cleared every time the dependent value updates.

Comment: I read some article about stale closure but it is not clear to me yet
I moved the updateScore part into another useEffect (update in the original post) and I have put isWinnerList in the dependency list. 2 problems:

- code inside socket.on('updateScore',...) is executed twice. (but the console.log I put inside the UseEffect before the socket.on() is only executed once.

my terminal throw a warning telling me I should add scoreList, setScoreList and socket into the dependency list. If I do that, then the amount of execution of socket.on() is increased each time and it becomes unbearable